# Limit country to just on in dokan plugin

Tags: wordpress, dokan

I am using dokan plugin and want to limit countries selection to just one in shipping page and setting page. I removed other countries from woocommerce i18n folder countries.php but nothing changes.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the WooCommerce country filter to achieve this result.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_countries', 'rt_modify_country_list' );

function rt_modify_country_list( $countries ){

    $countries = array(
        'BD' => 'Bangladesh',
        'CN' => 'China' 
    );

    return $countries;
}
```

Thanks